# ElementNotVisibleException not available in Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium, exception

I have some methods that are used to wait for an element to display, and in the try/catch for these methods, the catch is:

```
throw new ElementNotVisibleException()
```

I'm upgrading from Selenium 2.53 to Selenium 4, and ElementNotVisibleException() seems to not be available in Selenium 4. What should I replace it with? Is ElementNotInteractableException a suitable replacement?

Comment: Not an expert but this exception is available in python selenium 4. So should be available in java too

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why it's not resolving. I'm wondering if I'm missing a dependency or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since release 4.1.3, the method `ElementNotVisibleException()` has been removed from ***selenium/java/src/org/openqa/selenium***

See [v4.1.2](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/selenium-4.1.2-java/java/src/org/openqa/selenium), where the classes `ElementNotVisibleException` & `ElementNotSelectableException` exist.

See [v4.1.3](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/selenium-4.1.3-java/java/src/org/openqa/selenium), where the aforementioned classes have been removed.

This is due to the following:

> Selenium 4 is more strict regarding W3C WebDriver, and W3C WebDriver has nothing to say about visibility at this point. If an element is not visible, the driver in W3C mode should return a ElementNotInteractableException

So methods using the `ElementNotVisibleException.java` class will have to be updated to use `ElementNotInteractableException.java`

Confirmation here: [[ Bug]: ElementNotVisibleException class is not found in selenium 4.1.3. Getting compilation issues saying ElementNotVisibleException not found
#10538](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10538)

**Example:**

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public void selectUpload(String uploadType) throws Exception {

    WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@name,'uploadFileResultsInput')]"));

    int timeout = 0;
    Exception finalException = null;
    while (timeout < 5000) {
        try {
            new Select(dropdown).selectByVisibleText(uploadType);
            return;
        } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
            finalException = e;
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
        timeout += 500;
    }
    throw finalException;
}
```

to

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public void selectUpload(String uploadType) throws Exception {

    WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@name,'uploadFileResultsInput')]"));

    int timeout = 0;
    Exception finalException = null;
    while (timeout < 5000) {
        try {
            new Select(dropdown).selectByVisibleText(uploadType);
            return;
        } catch (ElementNotInteractableException e) {
            finalException = e;
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
        timeout += 500;
    }
    throw finalException;
}
```